# AS3 Blank copies of dynamically loaded images (works fine in Preview Mode, not in browser)

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, browser, copy

In AS3 I am loading an image at runtime using loaderContainer.load(new URLRequest(nameofpic)). The image loads perfectly fine, but then I need to copy the image into a number (24) of MCs and this is where it gets tricky.

The problem is, I can run it **perfectly fine** in preview mode, got all the 24 copies, but whenever I try running it in Firefox or IE, the images aren't displayed. No errors, just blank spaces.

It works with images present when exporting, both on stage or in the library -- their copies are visible in both preview mode and in the browser, but the browser doesn't want to work with dynamically loaded images

I have tried the draw() method as well as bitmapData.clone and again, they seem not to work in the browser, while they're fine in the preview mode.

Do you know what causes the problem and/if there is a list of more of such bugs?

DB

Comment: I think that you got a security error but you can't see it because your flash player isn't a debug version. Download and install a flash player debug version from [here](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) and tell us what you get.

Comment: There is a security issue, that's true. The thing is, I can actually see the loaded picture, it's the copying of it that produces the error -- the copied images show only in Preview, but neither in localHost nor on the server. This is why I think there is more at play here

Comment: In this case, if you are sure that the copying code that produced the error, could you show us that code ?